# why QQuickFramebufferObject::createRenderer not called?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I use Qt's official fboitem example, but it can't render properly. createRenderer should be called automatically inside the framework, and the log is printed and found that it is not called, so no rendering is performed.

But why isn't it called automatically?

Check out the Qt official mention that it is only called when the current program uses OpenGL rendering, but how to set the program to support OpenGL rendering?
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickframebufferobject.html

**this is simple code**

```
class FboInSGRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_NAMED_ELEMENT(Renderer)
public:
    Renderer *createRenderer() const;
};

class LogoInFboRenderer : public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer
{
public:
    LogoInFboRenderer()
    {
        logo.initialize();
    }

    void render() override {
        logo.render();
        update();
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) override {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        format.setSamples(4);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

    LogoRenderer logo;
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer *FboInSGRenderer::createRenderer() const
{
    qDebug() << "#createRenderer call......";
    return new LogoInFboRenderer();
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///scenegraph/fboitem/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFcED.png)

So where am I going wrong?

**My development environment:**

```
Qt 5.15.2 MinGW64
Windows 10 Pro
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz 2.30 GHz
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce MX330
```

Comment: I suppose that your code is probably somehow different from the Qt example. Also I suggest the Qt example works as expected. So all you need to compare and get the difference to localize the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved

My local registry was modified by some software

```
QMLSCENE_DEVICE =softwarecontext
```

So, just delete this and restart the computer and it will be ok

Comment: By registry you mean environment variable?

Comment: no.
win+R, enter regedit, open the registry, you will find a QMLSCENE_DEVICE, the content of the value is softwarecontext

This indicates that the current QML scene is rendered using a software context, which does not support OpenGL

So just delete this